# add remove data and show result without refreshing using jquery

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

Good day everyone!

I'm having problem how to add or remove data from database by just clicking on a link which come from the query from 2 tables.

here is my view for my query. anyway, I used LEFT JOIN for my query

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:3%;">#</th> 
      <th style="width:5%;">Code</th> <!-- from table 1 -->
      <th style="width:30%;">Name</th> <!-- from table 1 -->
      <th style="width:8%;">Price</th> <!-- from table 2 -->
      <th style="width:8%;">Paid</th> <!-- from table 2 -->
      <th style="width:15%;">Date Added</th> <!-- from table 2 -->
      <th style="width:10%"></th> <!-- show (+)add if t1.code != t2.code else show (x)remove -->
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php
  $i=0;
  foreach ($members->result() as $d) {
    $i++;
  ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $d->indicode; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $d->title.'. '.$d->lastname.', '.$d->firstname ; ?></td>
      <td><?php 
      if($d->amount==''){}else{echo $d->amount;}
      ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $d->paid; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $d->date_active; ?></td>
      <td><?php if($d->paid=='unpaid'){?><a href="<?php echo base_url().'participation/remove_byadmin/'.$d->indicode; ?>" class="text-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Remove</a><?php } 
      if($d->date_active==''){?>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url().'participation/add_byadmin/'.$d->indicode; ?>" class="text-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add</a>
      <?php }
      ?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php
    if($d->paid == 'unpaid'){
      $sum += $d->amount;
    }
  }
  ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

if you notice at the last column I have a certain link their where in it will show the (x)remove if the code from table1 has equal code on table2, otherwhise it will show (+)add.

What I want to happen is, when I click the add button some of the data from table1 + other data to be define in my controller will be added to table2 and if I click the remove button or link the data will be remove from table2. After clicking those button, I need that the page will automatically show the data/result without refreshing the page.

I hope somebody can help me out from this chaos. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It will be much easier to notice links if there would be rendered HTML instead of mix of HTML and PHP code.

Comment: About question: if you want to send data without page reloading, use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). If you want to occur it after clicking on `<a>`, add custom `click` event handler, send data via `$.ajax()` in it and prevent default `<a>` behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for that. How could I possibly do that? sorry I'm Newbie with this stuff.

Comment: actually I want to show the image of my output but the reputation wasn't enough.

Comment: There is no need in image. There is need in rendered HTML source code.  About "how can it be done?" - take a look at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/10w7zaj1/). There is a small example what to do. This site is not about "write code for me", so if you understand the idea in fiddle, you will be able to make what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should read some following things:

1) Using ajax to post and load the data.

2) Change content of HTML node. Remove HTML node and add a new HTML node.

Example:

- If you're using two buttons like this for the code above:

  ```
  <button onclick="removeData(<?php echo indicode;?>)">Remove </button>
  <button onclick="addNew(<?php echo indicode;?>)"> Add </button >
  ```
- You need to identify your table, tbody and tr like this:

  ```
  <table id="yourTable">
     <tbody id="yourTbody">   
         <tr id="indicode">
         </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
  ```
- When you post data to server by using ajax or post.

  ```
  function removeData(id)
  {
      $.post("participation/remove_byadmin/"+id,{},function(data){ 
        //Here you can remove the tr corresponding indicode.
        //Or if your data is a fresh new table, you can change content of the table
        //by using data ($("#yourtable").html(data); - Just an example).
      }
  }

  function addNew(id)
  {
      $.post("participation/add_byadmin/"+id,{},function(data){ 
        //You have to find out what should do here
      }
  }
  ```
- On server you could write code like following:

  ```
  //This is just an example. You can read and understand.
  class Participation extends CI_Controller
  {
     function remove_byadmin(id)
     {
        $this->yourModel->deletebyID(id);
        echo $this->yourModel->getNewHTMLTable();
        //Or echo something that will return to browser and you can use it to modify your table
     }

     function add_byadmin(id)
     {
        //do something
        echo $this->yourModel->getNewHTMLTable(); 
        //Or echo something that will return to browser and you can use it to modify your table
     }
  }
  ```

  Sorry about my English.